# Flask's redirect does nothing without throwing any error

Tags: javascript, flask

When I call the JavaScript function `updateOnServer`, it sends a GET request that is processed by `update_scripts_params` and the code inside it runs fine: the json data gets saved to a file, no errors. But the `redirect` function behaves not in the way I expect it to. Instead of opening the respective URL in the browser, it does nothing.

The only change that I've noticed is how the request metadata changes in the dev tools:

- The name of the request changes to 'home'.
- The desired URL gets added to the request (don't know what that means):

```
URL: http://[WON'T DDOS ME]/scripts-params/update?data=[SOME DATA...]
URL: http://[WON'T DDOS ME]/home
```

Client-side JavaScript:

```js
function updateOnServer{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "/scripts-params/update?data=" + encodeURIComponent(someJSONstr);
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        xhr.send();
    };
```

Flask:

```py
@app.route('/scripts-params/update')
def update_scripts_params():
    json_str = request.args.get('data')

    with open('server_json_str.json', 'w') as f:
        f.write(json_str)

    return redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I'm a noob, so forgive me...

Answer (score 0):

I've solved the problem. The issue was that I was sending an AJAX request instead of simply redirecting to a URL while my Flask configuration was able to handle only such direct URL loading in the browser. Or something like that... I don't understand it completely.

So, for now, I've just simplified the JavaScript function to perform that simple redirecting to the desired URL:

```js
function updateOnServer (scriptsParams) {
    paramsStr = JSON.stringify(scriptsParams)
    var url = "/scripts-params/update?data=" + encodeURIComponent(paramsStr);
    location.replace(url)
```

Answer (score -1):

I am sorry, I don't have the reputation to ask questions in comments, answering here with the information you presented.
Try changing your code line for home to:

```
return redirect(url_for('app.home'))
```

There could be other problems as well on how you declare your app. Try print statement in the home function before return to check if it is even called.

Comment: Nah, doesn't work: `werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'app.home'. Did you mean 'home' instead?`